# NullReferenceException at Application.Run(new Main())

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

I am at my wit’s end. I have an application that likes to crash a few minutes into running with a `NullReferenceException` (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). Normally I could deal with that just fine, but when Visual Studio breaks out, it’s telling me the issue is happening at `Application.Run(new Main());`. I have no idea what to do to begin trouble shooting this. The Call Stack doesn’t help any because it just points to that `Application.Run(new Main());` line.

I went into the Exception window of Visual Studio (`CTRL + ALT + E`) and told it to report ALL exceptions to me. I was hoping it would find the issue before I get this `NullReferenceException`. But no luck.

What tools are available to me to help find this issue?

**EDIT:**

Here is the Call Stack as reported by Visual Studio:

```
StackTrace:
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay.DrawRoutes(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay.Render(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaintOverlays(Graphics g)
       at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Foxhunt.Client.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Foxhunt.Client\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace.

Comment: Also, what happens when you just set a break point on the Application.Run line and on the Exit line of code... If something is arbitrarily forcing your app to restart, that may show it...

Comment: Information added as requested. And I only can break on Application.Run when the application first runs. Next time anything breaks out it's me getting the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Select in the Exceptions dialog for NullReferenceException: When the exception is thrown - Break into the debugger.

Comment: You are using non-.NET controls in your form, maybe an ActiveX control.  You'll need to enable unmanaged debugging and turn on the Microsoft Symbol server to see more.

Comment: What does this "new Main()" mean? Is this some class with the name 'Main' instantiated or what?

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki Yes. Program.cs is creating my WinForm for the application. In this case, the form is called Main.

Comment: Disable Just My Code and look at the call stack again.  Also look at the **exception**'s stack trace.

Comment: @SLaks YOU ROCK!!!!!!!!!!! I didn't realize you could drill down to the exception's stack trace. It is happening in a third party library I am using where I just have the compiled dll. Not the source. I think I'll be able to resolve this.

Comment: @SLaks Problem solved. I never realized I could pull the StackTrace for the EXCEPTION. That was the ticket I needed to find the error. Even though it is happening in a third party dll, I was able to change how I interact with it to solve the problem. I am relieved! If you want to post an official answer, I will accept it so you get credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is actually being thrown in code in a third-party, but Visual Studio isn't showing you that.

Look at the exception's stack trace to see a full stack.

Answer (score 3):

There might be an unhandled exception somewhere in your code, try to add the following to see if it gives more information:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.ThreadException += ThreadException;
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Main());
}

private static void ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
}

private static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be in a few places this. Change your code to

```
var mf = new Main();
Application.Run(mf);
```

If the first line falls over, problem is somewhere in the constructor chain

if the second then it's somwhere in the initialisation chain

Start battering red spots on all the relevant methods in the Main() class and stepping until you track it down.

Comment: It bangs out on the second line. I know the constructor is good because I use the application for a few minutes before it happens (which by the way makes debugging it that much more fun because I have to wait for it).